# Given a metric space, $U$ an open cover, is $r(x)$ necessarily continuous?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

**I recently came across the following question:**

---

Let $M$ be a metric space, $\mathcal{U}$ an open cover of $M$. For each $x \in M$, define $r(x):= \sup \{0 < r \leq 1 | \exists U \in \mathcal{U} \text{ such that } \mathbb{B}(x,r) \subset U \}$.

Is $r(x):M \mapsto (0,1]$ necessarily continuous?

---

**After a small amount of thought, I guessed it is, and here is my proof:**

---

Fix $x \in M$. Let $\epsilon > 0$.

Let $R := r(x) = \sup \{0 < r \leq 1 | \exists U \in \mathcal{U} \text{ such that } \mathbb{B}(x,r) \subset U \}$.

Define $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{4} > 0$. Take $y \in \mathbb{B}(x,\delta)$.

We know as $R$ is a least upper bound that $\exists U \in \mathcal{U} \text{ such that } \mathbb{B}(x,R - \frac{\epsilon}{2}) \subset U$.

So for $z \in \mathbb{B} (y,R - \frac{3\epsilon}{4})$ , $d(z,x) \leq d(z,y) + d(x,y) < R - \frac{3\epsilon}{4} + \frac{\epsilon}{4} = R - \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

So $\mathbb{B} (y,R - \frac{3\epsilon}{4}) \subset \mathbb{B}(x,R - \frac{\epsilon}{2}) \subset U$.

Therefore, $r(y) > R - \epsilon$.

Now for the other bound, assume $r(y) \geq R + \epsilon$.

Then, in a similar vein to the above, $\exists U \in \mathcal{U} \text{ such that } \mathbb{B}(y,R + \frac{\epsilon}{2}) \subset U$.

So for $z \in \mathbb{B} (x,R + \frac{\epsilon}{4})$ , $d(z,y) \leq d(z,x) + d(x,y) < R + \frac{\epsilon}{4} + \frac{\epsilon}{4} = R + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

So $\mathbb{B}(x,R + \frac{\epsilon}{4}) \subset \mathbb{B}(y,R + \frac{\epsilon}{2}) \subset U$.

So either $R = 1$, and then $r(y) \geq 1 + \epsilon$ which is a contradiction, or $R$ was not actually a least upper bound, which is also contradictory.

Therefore $R - \epsilon < r(y) < R + \epsilon$.

So $r(x)$ is continuous.

---

*Does this seem correct? Is there a smoother way to do it? Or have I completely missed something and someone can provide a counterexample?!*

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For $U$, $f_U(x)=0$ for $x\in U^c$ and $f_U(x)=\min\ \{1, \sup\ \{r|B(x,r)\subset U\} \}$. Then $f_U$ is continuous. Further, $F(x)=\sup\ \{ f_U(x)|U$ is in cover$\}$ is continous.